# Access same svg container value

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I use this function to access the SVG container :

```
   function getSvgContainer() {
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 1200)
                .attr("height", 1200)
                .attr("text-align", "center");

        return svgContainer
    }
```

I would like write this function so that if it's invoked multiple times the same
`svgContainer` is returned. How can this be achieved ?

Should I check if "svg" is appended to the body and if it is then return that
same container ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a constructor function. 
Please check the example below.

```js
(function() {

    // constructor function
    var SVGclass = function(){
        this.createSVG();
    }
    
    SVGclass.prototype.createSVG = function() {
        this.svgContainer = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 1200)
                    .attr("height", 1200)
                    .attr("text-align", "center");
    };
    
    SVGclass.prototype.getSVG = function() {
        return this.svgContainer;
    };
    
    
    // demo code to show usage of class
    var svgMain = new SVGclass();
    
    var svg = svgMain.getSVG();
    
    svg.append('circle') 
        .attr({'cx': 50, 'cy': 50, 'r': 25})
        .attr('fill', 'red');

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: does this not mean that everytime "var svgMain = new SVGclass();" is invoked a new instance is created ? As "createSVG" is called by "new SVGclass();" ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just create the svgMain once and use it as a global object. Alternatively you could add the svg container in your html and store just the selection of `d3.select(#svgContainer)` in your object.